# ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION when trying to use localhost .dev in Chrome

Tags: localhost

Today I got this error when trying to access local domains specified in apache httpd-vhosts.conf. It happened for the 1st time with a .dev domain, so it seemed plausible that in light of [recent news](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/15/02/28/1333231/google-taking-over-new-tlds) Goggle finally got it.

However, I tried with other domain names (eg. .abb or .loc) and the error persists. I' m working with UniServerZ on Windows7 and Chrome explains the "ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION" error roughly as "this website uses new top level domain name. Contact your network administrator if it used to work".  It indeed used to work with .dev domains.

Now, trying to google ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION brings very few results and I have no network administrator to contact. :-)

The question is: is this me and possibly my hosts/vhosts settings or the world's fault? What local domain names should be good now to use for a local dev server?

Comment: Take a look to this resource:

https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/name-collision-2013-12-06-en

Comment: If you need a local TLD domain name, maybe use .local or .localdomain... IIRC at least one of those two are reserved for local use and will not be issued to any registrar anytime soon (as is the case with .invalid for invalid TLD examples, or example.com/.net for domain examples).

Comment: @Archimedix `.local` may be problematic as well: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204684

Comment: Do you have the domain name correctly listed in your hosts file?  I got this error until I added it.

Comment: It might be strange or not, but it used to work without any entry in the hosts file, just with a vhosts entry. Now it stopped, probably due to new tlds being registered but since with hosts you can overwrite any domain it works again now.

Comment: .local is definitely problematic. iOS (after some version) doesn't seem to even try to resolve it.

Comment: Per RFC 2608, Section 2, .test, .example, .invalid and .localhost are the only TLDs guaranteed to never be allocated. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606#section-2

Comment: This is a problem with Google Chrome. It is a known issue, and has been for years. It is currently a "wont-fix" issue. Chrome doesn't properly work with the local DNS stack. Even with `/etc/hosts` entries and/or local DNS, Google Chrome still fails. It does, however, work fine with Firefox, Lynx, and Epiphany. Definitely a Google Chrome bug. I have been using `.dev` for my local development for many many years and plan to continue to do so for a long time to come. COntrary to what people may say, you are perfectly safe to continue to use `.dev` as your TLD.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The pseudo domain name(s) you are using are being registered as a new top level domain.

The DNS returns `127.0.53.53` which is a signal that this TLD is being registered by someone. Chrome versions from M43 have a this new way of relaying the error message to the user.

Use a domain name you own. Possibly using the full name like "localhost.dev.$yourdomain" could help you here depending on your setup.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Can I just make up a subdomain of a domain that I use for my personal website and put it in vhosts file or 1. do I need to buy one specifically for local use 2. should I set up anything besides the vhosts entry?

Comment: Just vhost entries alone does not suffice. You also need to setup matching DNS records. In case of linux it can be `/etc/hosts` or if you want other to be able to use it you need to register a domain and setup matching A records.

Comment: Nah, it's for personal use only. So redirecting a subdomain of any existing domain under my control to localhost in `hosts` file + entry in `vhosts` to direct the subdomain to a local directory should be enough?

Comment: @konrad with /etc/hosts the domain does not even have to be under your control.

Comment: `/etc/hosts` entries for a TLD you don't own are still a bad idea due to DNS leakage. A hostname typo will result in the real DNS servers for your "appropriated" domain being queried. From there what happens is anyone's guess; `NXDOMAIN` response if your luck continues, or wildcard DNS responses redirecting browsers to malware sites if you're not. If you *are* going to do this, make sure to edit all of your `/etc/resolv.conf` files to remove the domain that you don't own from the `search` path.

Comment: 127.0.53.53 is basically an error message. It's a special IP addresses that is used by ICANN to prevent DNS name collisions with the new gTLDs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662590/domain-foo-bar-points-127-0-53-53-why

Answer (score 2):

It *appears* that Google wants to use `.dev` only for internal puposes. Under that assumption it seems to be safe to host a "fake" dev zone on your internal DNS server

Comment: Do you mean it's possible to circumvent the error somehow with correct local settings? What should I set up for this?

Comment: Assuming you already have a private DNS server, look at its documentation for how to set up a "split horizon".

Answer (score 2):

ICANN has released new public gTLD-s, such as `.dev`. You can either add the local address to your `C:\\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` file or change the site's address in your web server config file.

Answer (score 2):

Use `example.local` instead of `example.dev` and it works for me.

Comment: This is a very good workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and I fixed when stop using more than 9 domains.

You can check if your host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) have more than 9 domains